# VW Golf 6 2010 error code P2455

Tags: vw, dtc

While driving, I heard a beeping sound from dashboard. When I looked at it, it showed "glow plug icon," it blinked 3 time and on the screen it said something like "Engine Fault - Workshop". 
[image]

Then I stopped, turned the car off and back on and everything was ok. After 3 km of driving, the same thing happens again, I turned the car off, and back on and it did not happen now for 3 days. I checked it with OBD software (obdautodoctor) and it shows "Pending DTC":

Error code:P2455

System:Powertrain

Description:Particulate Filter Pressure Sensor "A" Circuit High

After this, I was driving for about 150 km and nothing happened, the car runs fine as normal, no error on dashboard ...

Should I be worried? For me it looks like (as P2455 error description says) that there was some weird pressure in the DPF filter (didn't even knew that I have one :S) which was registered by sensor A (looks like there are more of those sensors) and that error did pop up. Should I do DPF regeneration procedure ?

Comment: In my opinion, you should trouble shoot it to find out what caused the issue. It may be running ok now, but the issue could come back again but worse. Possible even strand you somewhere. Better to be proactive about it.

Comment: Are you able to get the VAG code instead of the p2455? Not saying the code is wrong, but generic OBD2 codes aren't always reliable. Which engine do you have? Has the DPF ever been replaced?

Comment: Thanks for corrections. Yeah i agree, but i think this was some temporal pressure around DPF which was registered as DTC. Not sure. If DPF is full or clogged, i would have constant error and different icon on dashboard. @Ben yeah, i used some generic OBD tool. I will check it with VCDS. Engine is 1.6 TDi. I think DPF was never replaced, because car has 140k km. When it should be replaced ? I was reading that they are regenerated or something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer myself and eventually help someone in future with Golf 6, year 2010 (im pretty sure it will help with other diesels specially from VW group), error code was:

P2455 - Diesel Particulate Filter Pressure Sensor "A" Circuit High. I found this error code with some generic OBD scanning tool, VCDS from Ross Tech and VAS software (always same description).
So the solution to the problem was just to replace "Diesel Particulate Filter Pressure Sensor" (that was said to me by VW expert guy). I bought new one 60€, disconnected old one, setup new one, clear codes and everything works fine. You need to pay attention to buy exact one you had before (check numbers on it).

Here is picture of it how it looks and works (picture taken from http://www.sensata.com/hvor/exhaust/dps-differential-pressure-sensor.htm):
[image: Diesel Particulate Filter Pressure Sensor Explained]

one more roughly explaining situation (picture taken from http://www.hho4free.com/diesel_emissions_control.html):

[image: Diesel Particulate Filter Pressure Sensor Position and rought schema]

another one (this is actually how it looks on VW Golf 6 2010):

[image: Clear look of Diesel Particulate Filter Pressure Sensor]
[image]